# Zend Zend_Form Layouting

Tags: zend-form, zend-framework

i have an input-Element, that should be layouted through a css-class:

class="ok", default or when there is no error by validating this field
and
class="error", when there is an error by validating this field.

How can i achieve that?

Fesp

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is to `foreach` through the form elements after you've called `isValid` and add the class name to each element based on its `hasErrors` status.
Another solution would be to add a Decorator to the form decorators, which will do the same.